# In semantic HTML does the class attribute mean anything in the absence of CSS or Javascript?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

For example, does the class `film_review` mean anything in `<article class="film_review">` (example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)) if there's no CSS or Javascript interacting with the page, or does it provide semantic information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't provide an information that contemporary browsers would interpret or use without CSS or Javascript per se.

However it can carry semantic information - see e.g. [microformats](http://microformats.org/). For example, you could put an hcard

```
<div id="hcard-John-Doe" class="vcard">
  <span class="fn">John Doe</span>
  <div class="org">Cool Institute, Inc.</div>
  <div class="adr"><span class="locality">Prague</span></div>
</div>
```

on your page and it carries a semantic information. A search engine like Google could infer that "John Doe" is a name of a person located in "Prague". There are other microformats that can represent geo information, calendar events, etc.

Anyone can write their own processor of HTML documents that would interpret `class` attribute values, so the answer is *yes, it provides semantic information*.

Quoting from [hcard microformat example](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-examples):

> Per the HTML4.01 specification, authors should be using the  element to indicate the "contact information for a document or a major part of a document." E.g.
>
> <address>
>   <a href="http://tantek.com/">Tantek Çelik</a></address>
>
> By adding hCard to such existing semantic XHTML, you can explicitly indicate the name of the person, their URL, etc.:
>
> <address class="vcard">
>      <a class="fn url" href="http://tantek.com/">Tantek Çelik</a>
>   
> </address>

Answer (score 2):

It provides semantics purely in the sense that it semantically connects that element with other elements of the same class.

There's no rule which states that anything (specifically CSS and/or JavaScript in this case) must *use* that class.  The class itself is simply part of the markup and is coincidentally being ignored by the current styling rules.

You might have other elements with the `film_review` class, and they are "semantically" connected in the sense that they represent "film reviews" in the markup.  That's really all semantic information is... context about the thing being represented in the code.  Well-named classes can provide such additional context.

But there's nothing special that the browser is going to do with this information.  It's just there in case anybody (styling, code, or even just somebody looking at the markup) wants to know that this `article` belongs to a named class of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Semantics on HTML5 are more oriented on standarizing the most used elements around the web. As described on [HTML Semantic Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp):

> With HTML4, developers used their own favorite attribute names to style page elements:
>   header, top, bottom, footer, menu, navigation, main, container, content, article, sidebar, topnav, ...
>   This made it impossible for search engines to identify the correct web page content.
>   With HTML5 elements like: `<header> <footer> <nav> <section> <article>`, this will become easier.

So an element so specific as a "Film Review" would not provide that much semantic information at HTML5 level.

Answer (score 0):

That depends. Who and what else is processing your HTML?

For example, microformats sometimes use classes to add semantic information to elements which don't naturally possess rich semantics. In that case, neither ECMAScript nor CSS process that information, but a microformats parser might. `film_review` doesn't belong to any well-known microformat, however.

Answer (score 0):

Everything on the page gets parsed (read) by a search-engine, so your answer is, YES, it does provide semantic information, however there are different weighted value associated with different HTML tokens (elements, attribute-names, attribute-values).

However what really defines how much weight a HTML token gets, is really dependent on the type of document that you declare it is (HTML4/HTML5), the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag at the top of your page declares that to the search-engine bot/parser what type of document it is, which in turn controls the search-engine bot's parsing-schema (behavior) on how to read your document.

The entire purpose of HTML5 was to provide "semantics", allowing you to use different tags so you can markup/define your document giving content more importance allowing search-engines to understand it better. This allows the search-engine a much better way to then supply the end-user, whom is searching for something with more relevant content associated with their search term... if your not using HTML5 and using HTML4 then the bots are relying mostly on HTML attributes to define the content within tags such as a `<div>` which provides no semantic meaning to the content inside it.